# jQuery.Data set's or get's wrong item

Tags: javascript, jquery, selector

I am using something similair to this:

```
$("input").each(function(number,element)
{
    var inputField=$(element);

    if(inputField.data("FieldLocalizationStrings") == null)
        inputField.data("FieldLocalizationStrings", []);
}
```

And to add data:

```
var data=inputField.data("FieldLocalizationStrings");
data.push({Language:inputField.attr("language"),Value:inputField.val()});
```

But when i try to retreive, it seems to ignore on which DOM element it has been saved and just loads it like it was all saved on the same element. Anyone an idea why this would happen? i have used the same technique before and it proved to work, but now i can't figure out why this is hapening.
I confirmed it does not save it to multiple input fields, but when loading it acts like it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**
Added [a fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/yQJNd/)

```
$("input").each(function(number,element)
{
    var inputField=$(element);

    if(inputField.data("FieldLocalizationStrings") == null)
        inputField.data("FieldLocalizationStrings", [
            {
                Language:inputField.attr("language"),
                Value:inputField.val()
            }
    ]);

    //If later you want to append to the data
    inputField.data("FieldLocalizationStrings").push({/* Your data */})
}
```

Comment: Can't do something like that in this case, it is added over time, not (only) after initialization but that would not solve the loading issue i'm affraid.

Comment: @Update, added the line which would make the "data" var, this is already the same as you suggested right or am i missing something?

Comment: I'll make a fiddle for you in a minute and you can check it out

Comment: @MichaelOverhorst - check the fiddle

Answer (score 0):

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/ - as for documentation you'll get value as second parameter. If you want set data for an element you should use this.

Comment: Already is like stated in the documentation, the variable names do not matter in JavaScript afaik.